# Unrecognized selector error when I tap on my Email button

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector

```
class ContactViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func emailSenden(_ sender: Any) {

    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("Mail services are not available")
        return
    } else {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["someone@example.com"])
            mail.setSubject("Message to you")
            mail.setMessageBody("Hallo,\n", isHTML: false)

            present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)

            mail.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

    }
}
```

This is my code. The problem is that every time I want to run this in my application I get this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[My_App.ContactViewController email:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b22430'

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: what s the purpose are you used this `mail.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thats to also have an animation when the user closes the email again.

Comment: no need of this that the reason it is crash hide the line and check once

Comment: When exactly do you get the error? Which line of code exactly causes the error?

Comment: I don't really now it just says thread 1: signal SIGABRT in the App Delegate

Comment: You don't know when the error happens? Like maybe when you tap some button.

Comment: It happens when I tap the emailSenden (German for sendEmail) button

Comment: When I tap that button the whole app crashes

Comment: That's because your button is connected to a non-existent method named `email`. Your code has a method named `emailSenden`. Connect your button to the proper method or rename your method.

Comment: @me21 Check your storyboard connection for this button and make sure there are not more then one outlet connected for this button.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy :-)

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma

Comment: Both really helpful comments :-)

Comment: @me2no issues mate.:)1